# Find the number of trailing zeroes.

Tags: number-theory, factorial, prime-factorization

Find the number of trailing zeroes.

$k=1^1\times 2^2\times 3^3\times \cdots \times100^{100}$

It usually involves calculating number of $5$'s in

$5^5\times 10^{10}\times 15^{15}\times \cdots\times 100^{100}$

calulating 5's one by one is pretty boring and time consuming are their any other methods.

Comment: Very similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128755/how-many-0s-are-in-the-end-of-this-expansion/1128770)

Comment: @avz thnks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was recently working on this.

$k=1^1\times 2^2\times 3^3\times \cdots \times100^{100} = $$\frac{(100!)^{100}}{1!\cdot2!\cdot3!....\cdot99!}$$  $

Now calculate trailing zeroes in the factorials... using the de Poliganc's formula (No need to count fives): [Derive a formula to find the number of trailing zeroes in $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111385/derive-a-formula-to-find-the-number-of-trailing-zeroes-in-n)

Use the formulae there & then customize it according to tailor it to this problem to solve it.

---

Edit: Alternative is:-
Number of fives in the expression involves counting number of fives from all the multiples of five.

Easiest trick=> $5^5\times 10^{10}\times 15^{15}\times \cdots\times 100^{100}$

Number of fives = Sum of all the terms of the powers of the above expression! Therefore, sum would be  $5+10+15....+100$ This is easily solvable using arithmetic progression sum formula.

$100 = 5 +(n-1)5$ => $n = 20 $

Sum = $\frac{n(2a+(n-1)d)}{2}=\frac{20(2*5+(20-1)5)}{2}= 1050 $

$25^{25}=5^{50},\\ 50^{50}=5^{100}\cdot2^{50}\\ 75^{75}=5^{150}\cdot3^{75}\\ 100^{100}=5^{200}\cdot4^{100}\\$

Therefore number of zeroes, will be $1050+\frac{50+100+150+200}{2} = 1300$ Zeroes.

Comment: do i have to calculate no of zero's in $1!\cdot2!\cdot3!....\cdot99!$ one by one ?

Comment: You can brute solve it using a computer. Otherwise, calculating the number of trailing zeroes in a factorial is easier than doing so for a square. (Use a computational engine online for quickly getting the output of number of zeroes after having inputted the formula.) Unfortunately, I still think it's a bit inefficient....But certainly easier than the problem we started out with! If your looking for a magically fast answer, best bet is to do some computer coding.

Comment: this is a pen and paper question, calculators not allowed.

Comment: Then you can do another thing, which you can see after I update my post. Wait for two minutes..

Comment: Done! Found the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks very nice , but you have to bit carefull as
$25^{25}=5^{50},\\
50^{50}=5^{100}\cdot2^{50}\\
75^{75}=5^{150}\cdot3^{75}\\
100^{100}=5^{200}\cdot4^{100}\\$                                              

 so total number of zero's =$1050+\frac{50+100+150+200}{2}=1300$

Comment: Agreed. Slipped my mind. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Above expression is same as $$\frac{(100!)^{100}}{1!\cdot2!\cdot3!....\cdot99!}$$
calculate trailing zeroes in $100!$ raise it by 100 calculate number of trailing zeroes for other factorials too,a pattern can be observed.
Number of trailing zeroes in n! is given by,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}[\frac {n}{5^i}]$$